# transfer ERC20 on behalf of token owner after a payment of ether occurs

Tags: solidity

I have the following scenario:

I have a contract to generate a limited amount of erc20 tokens. User A buys X amount of this token. Then user A wants to sell some of his tokens, for X amount of ether, then user B wants to buy tokens of user A, how can I automatically transfer tokens from user A to user B when the transfer of ether from user B to user A has been successful be transfer?

Do I need a second contract to handle this kind of operation?

Answer (score 1):

You may have two options,

1. Play around with Escrow SmartContracts (Like [Openzeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/payment#escrow)) and modify it as per your need.
2. 

- Use `ERC20 Approve(spender,amount)` on User B, to get allowance for your contract to spend on behalf of B. (spender : Your contract address)
- Run a web3 script to listen on events to catch the corresponding transaction of sending ether from B->A ,
- once the ether is transferred, you can place a function call to smart contract to spend the token from B to A

Comment: Can you help me with the web3 part of listening on the event ? I am testing some code of web3 but they are shown deprecated. It would be great if you provide me some good resources on web3.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what stack/framework are you using for your app?

Comment: I am using nodejs. I can call function from smart contract with web3 which does not have any parameter. But I am getting error at the time of calling functions which contain some parameter, those functions basically cost gas price and related to transactions.

Answer (score 0):

In your ERC20 Contract implementation, you can have a mapping of address -> eth, where the eth represents the selling price each user has set up.

Now, when a user "sells" their token, they can [allow](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-approve-address-uint256-) the same contract to transfer X amount of tokens from their balance which they want to sell.

And to sell, you can create a payable function that receives ether, and via parameter a seller address. This function will dynamically ( using the address received on the mapping we created at the beginning ) transfer X tokens to the buyer, using that seller's token price and the amount of ether received.

For example: If 1TKs = 0.5ETH, and the buyer sends 2eth, the contract will transfer 4TKS.

### Recomendation.

Usually, the token contract and the seller/buyer functions are done in different contracts for security reasons, for example having the actual token, and the token shop separated on different contracts.

### Disclaimer.

This is the simplest implementation I could think of, but it will accomplish your requirements.